# Access the value of smart select via javascript in framwork7

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I want to access the value of smart multiple select via javascript. I have no clue. Please help someone.
[Framework7 smart multiple select](https://framework7.io/docs/smart-select.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access multiple selected values by using ".each()" and passing it to array.

Ex:

This is the multiple select:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="item-link smart-select">
    <!-- "multiple" attribute for multiple select-->
    <select name="car" multiple>
      <!-- options grouped within "optgroup" tag-->
        <option value="honda" selected>Honda</option>
        <option value="lexus">Lexus</option>
        <option value="mazda">Mazda</option>
        <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
        <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
    </select>
    <div class="item-content">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="item-title">Car</div>
      </div>
    </div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Passing selected values to array:

```js
var cars = [];
     $$('select[name="car"] option:checked').each(function () {
        cars.push(this.value);
     });

    console.dir(cars); //or console.dir(cars);
```

Result: `(2) ["honda", "lexus"]`

Comment: You can, of course, also get the text of the selected items, using `cars.push(this.text);`

Answer (score 1):

Old question but ranks on Google, and since I just wasted 2 hours on this here's how to do it with v6 & vuejs:

```
<f7-list-item title="I feel"
                    class="mood"
                    smart-select
                    :smart-select-params="{openIn: 'popover', closeOnSelect: true}">
        <select name="mood">
          <option value="" selected>Please choose</option>
          <option value="happy">Happy</option>
          <option value="sad">Sad</option>
        </select>
      </f7-list-item>

...

      const mood = f7.smartSelect.get(".mood .smart-select").getValue()
```

With vuejs the `.mood` class in the `f7-list-item` gets added to the parent of the element that gets the `.smart-select` class so you need to pass both selectors otherwise `f7.smartSelect.get` won't be able to find the object.